# Join rows with fuzzy time data to regular time slots

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join, generate-series

I have PostgreSQL table that look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tb1 (
id integer,
name text,
date date,
time time without tz
);
```

With following query I am creating table with row_id's and time starting from 09:00 with increment every 10 minutes

```
(
SELECT g AS id, '09:00'::time + '10 min'::interval * (g-1) AS time
FROM   generate_series (1,10) g
) g
left JOIN tb1 AS t1 USING (time)
```

After join I have new table which contain row's from table tb1 but only if time in tb1 have same time as one generated by '09:00'::time + '10 min'::interval * (g-1) AS time.

How to achieve that all rows with time from tb1 is "inserted" into generated table. If time generated is same than time from tb1 then no duplication should happen.

Comment: Can you guarantee there is no more than *one* row for every 10-min-slot in `tb1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can guarantee there is no more than one row for every 10-min-slot in `tb1`, this should be fastest:

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT g AS id, '09:00'::time + '10 min'::interval * (g-1) AS time_slot
   FROM   generate_series (1,10) g
   ) g
LEFT  JOIN tb1 t1 ON t1.time >= g.time_slot
                 AND t1.time <  g.time_slot + '10 min'::interval
```

The join condition is [sargable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable), so an index on `time` can be used.

If there can be multiple rows per 10-min-slot in the source and you need a single row in the result, you need to aggregate one way or the other. Like:

```
SELECT g.id, g.time_slot, t1.time, min(t1.whatever) AS min_whatever
FROM  (
   SELECT g AS id, '09:00'::time + '10 min'::interval * (g-1) AS time_slot
   FROM   generate_series (1,10) g
   ) g
LEFT  JOIN tb1 t1 ON t1.time >= g.time_slot
                 AND t1.time <  g.time_slot + '10 min'::interval
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3;
```

Comment: In case of multiple row's within 10min slot I need all of them to be inserted.

Comment: @jack_oneal: All of them with the same `time_slot`? Then first query should serve. I clarified a bit.

Comment: No, let say that you have rows with time 09:10, 09:15 and 09:20 then all 3 should be joined to t1.

Comment: Bottom line is that I will have 2 tables, one with time and other without time. Those with time must be in t1, those without time should be inserted with 10 min time interval

Comment: Solved it, SELECT DISTINCT before everything, and now it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I auspect you want a full outer join.

```
(
SELECT g AS id, '09:00'::time + '10 min'::interval * (g-1) AS time
FROM   generate_series (1,10) g
) g
FULL OUTER JOIN tb1 AS t1 USING (time)
```

Comment: Thanks. I already tried that. Problem is that although "name" from tb1 is inserted, "time" from tb1 is not added. As a result I can only see time generated by "'09:00'::time + '10 min'::interval * (g-1)" and then last row is name from tb1 but without time. I need time from tb1 to be "inserted" into column as well.

Comment: @jack_oneal have you got some sample data I can use?